# Encriptar Contraseña en Moodle

Tags: moodle, md5, encriptación

Tengo dudas acerca de como descifrar el encriptado de `Moodle`, tengo entendido que usa el tipo de encriptación **MD5**, pero a la vez hace una doble encriptación que no sé cual es. Lo que requiero es hacer esa misma encriptación para poder hacer un validador de contraseñas en `Moodle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según entiendo Moodle utiliza algo así como:

```
MD5(CONCAT(password, password_salt))
```

Ese `password_salt` lo encuentras en el archivo `config.php` en la variable `$CFG->passwordsaltmain`

[Referencia 1](https://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Password_salting#Disabling_password_salting)
 [Referencia 2](https://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Password_salting)
 [Referencia 3](http://tlaca3lel.blogspot.cl/2013/05/cambiar-contrasena-de-moodle-con-salt.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sólo hay que recordar que MD5 es un algoritmo de hash, no de cifrado. En teoría, un hash no es reversible, un cifrado, sí.

Para validar contraseñas, lo tendrías que hacer es algo como lo siguiente:

1) Tomas la contraseña que te dieron en un login

2) Calcular su hash (incluyendo la información de password_salt)

3) Comparas el resultado con el valor que previamente se había almacenado para dichas contraseña.

4) Si los hash son iguales, la contraseña es válida.

Comment: Esa es la idea, el problema al momento de calcular el hash, hasta el momento no he podido.